# How to update environment variable dynamically before npm start in React (variable for IP address)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables

Actually, I am trying to set the REACT_APP_DEPLOY_DOMAIN variable automatically in .env file.

below is one method I tried to achieve the solution to this issue.

below is my script file in which I am getting my IP address

```
const os = require("os");

const networkInterfaces = os.networkInterfaces();
const ip = networkInterfaces["Wi-Fi"][1]["address"];

REACT_APP_DEPLOY_DOMAIN = `http://${ip}`;
console.log(`http://${ip}`);
return `http://${ip}`;
```

below is the env variable in .env file

```
REACT_APP_DEPLOY_DOMAIN =  http://192.168.1.114
```

And also I tried to update it from the start command but it is setting it as the exact command

```
    "start": "set REACT_APP_DEPLOY_DOMAIN=node ./src/components/getIp.js && react-scripts start",
```

And also my script file is not running when I try to run the below command.

```
"start": "node ./src/components/getIp.js && react-scripts start",
```

Comment: This does not sound like a variable type to go in a dotenv. I am not sure about your usecase, but if you want, you can manually keep track of your local ip address and update the .env accordingly. Or alternatively, you can open up a little node server that returns your local ip for you which you can then use in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Update the start command to this, it works on Linux/Mac. Hopefully, it'll also work on windows

```bash
"start": "set REACT_APP_DEPLOY_DOMAIN=$(node ./src/components/getIp.js) && react-scripts start",
```

Comment: sorry bro it is not working

Comment: command is setting the exact value (without $ sign) = (node ./src/components/getIp.js)